# Counting runs/set of 1's in a binary number

Tags: c#, bitwise-operators

I want to count the runs of 1's in a binary sequence with the help of bitwise operators.

I have searched for similar topics but found different answers from what I'm looking for. Hamming weight is also different as it counts the number of 1's in the binary.

For example, if I have the binary 001101011101, I should have 4 runs of 1's as they are the sets/group of 1's divided by 0's in between them.

I know how to use bitwise operators in C# but I am not really able to use them collectively inside one program.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you give a code sample? A specific question is how is the binary represented, is it a string, a uint etc?

Comment: How is the binary given? int? string?

Comment: the binary would be unsigned integer ulong/uint.

Answer (score 6):

if you have a string representation of your binary number, then you just need to split the string on "0":

```
var binaryString = "0011011101110001";

var count = binaryString
    .Split(new [] { '0' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Count();
```

If your number is stored in an `int` then it's a simple matter to convert to a string:

```
int value = 12345;
var binaryString = Convert.ToString(value, 2);
```

Comment: `Split` return array, so we can use `Length` property instead call function `Count`

Comment: @Grundy Indeed you can. Personally I prefer `Count` as it's more readable, but it's really only opinion.

Comment: This answer is based on the incorrect assumption that the binary number is stored in a string. I think the binairy number is stored in a number like `int` or `long`, since the OP is talking about bitwise operators.

Comment: @MartinMulder, in this case OP can just do `.ToString(2)` or something like :-)

Comment: @MartinMulder Added that in just in case.

Comment: @Skorunka 1 would seem like the correct answer to me. Why would you think otherwise?

Comment: Oh, my bad! I was actually writing an algorithm for counting ones in a binary number. I will delete my comment.

Answer (score 2):

The leftmost 1 in a run of ones has the properties that it occurs exactly once per run, it is a 1 itself, and it has a zero to the left of it (or nothing, but that's an implied zero).

We can isolate all the leftmost ones of runs using the last two properties:

```
uint leftmost = x & ~(x >> 1);
```

And then the ones can be counted using any bit counting algorithm.

The same sort of thing can be done with the rightmost ones of every group as well, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Shift though all the bits. Do this 32 times and analyze the first bit every time. It is becomes 1, the numbers of groups is increased. If the bit becomes 0, a new group could start.

```
bool found = false;
int numberOfGroups = 0;
int bits = 0x035D;
for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
{
    int bit = bits & 1;
    if (!found && bit == 1) 
    {
        numberOfGroups++;
        found = true;
    }
    else if (found && bit == 0) 
    {
       found = false;
    } 
    bits >>= 1;
}
```